# ng-click not calling to type Script function

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to implement my angular js code with Type script but my ng click is not working.
It's my controller code:-

```
module CustomerSearch.controllers {
    export class CustomerCtrl {
        static $inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache'];

        constructor(protected $scope: ICustomerScope,
            protected $http: ng.IHttpService,
            protected $templateCache: ng.ITemplateCacheService) {
            $scope.search = this.search;
        }
        public search = (search: any) => {
            debugger;
            var Search = {
                AccountId: search.AccountId,
                checkActiveOnly: search.checkActiveOnly,
                checkParentsOnly: search.checkParentsOnly,
                listCustomerType: search.listCustomerType
            };




            this.$scope.customer = [];
            this.$scope.ticket = [];
            this.$scope.services = [];

            var url = "someUrl"; // '<%=ResolveUrl("API/Search/PutDoSearch")%>'
            this.$http.put(url, Search).
                success((data, status, headers, config) => {
                debugger;
                this.$scope.cust_File = data[0].customers;
                this.$scope.ticket_file = data[0].tickets;
                this.$scope.service_file = data[0].services;
            }).
                error((data, status) => {
                console.log("Request Failed");
            });
        }
    }
    angular.module("CustomerSearch").controller("CustomerSearch.controllers.QuickSearchController");
}
```

I am trying to call my type script class using ng click and than it will move to my api but there might be some problem that ng-click is not processed.

Comment: Where is the partial where you have `ng-click=...`? And is it possible to reference this.search in the constructor?

Comment: It's in my aspx page where i have used my ng-click @hgoebl

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this error by Registering My Controller in type script.and than making changes in sequence of references

Answer (score 1):

In short `search` is not the search you think it is. Here are a few reasons:

- The class constructor isn't actually executed: try putting a console.log in there.
- The term `search` is pointing to some other js object. Select the element in the UI when running in chrome and log out : `console.log(angular.element($0).scope())`